# Perl system call mplayer, transition between videos varies

Tags: perl, ipc, mplayer

I'm only few weeks into perl, and I am trying to run the codes below:

```
sub runVideo {
    system('mplayer -fs video1.mpeg2 video2.mpeg2');
    return;
}

runVideo();
system('some other processes in background&');
runVideo();
```

Basically I run video1 and video2 for two times, first time which is just the videos, second time with some application running at the background, doesn't matter what apps are running, since I'm running the videos in fullscreen mode.

**Problem:**

**On the first run, the transition from video1 to video2 takes about 1-2 seconds.
While on the second run, the transition from video1 to video2 takes less than a second.**

**Question:**

**Why is the transition time differs? Could it be the videos are still in the memory so it took shorter time to load it?**

**What other alternatives or workarounds to get a same transition time?**

Comment: Flush the cache? `man mplayer` Or try with copies of the files `system('mplayer -fs video3.mpeg2 video4.mpeg2')` This is hardly a perl question though.

Comment: You didn't indicate what OS you're on, but I've assumed a Unix-like one because (a) that's what I know; (b) that's normally what mplayer runs on.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i'm running on Meego 1.2

Answer (score 0):

The answer is likely in caching effects. Either the video, or the codecs required to play it, weren't in memory for video2. But of course the second time you do it, they are.

There are a couple of things you can try—depending on the exact reason the delay is a problem:

- You can try the `-fixed-vo` option to mplayer (if you're using mplayer 1.x; its default in 2.x I believe). This will prevent the jarring vo deinit/reinit cycle.
- You can (and probably should) run mplayer in `-slave` mode (also probably with `-idle`). This will give you much more control over it.
- You can pre-cache whatever data is taking a while. The way to do this on Unix-like systems is `posix_fadvise(int fd, off_t offset, off_t len, int advice)` with an advice of `POSIX_FADV_WILLNEED`. Alternatively, on Linux, `readahead(int fd, off64_t offset, size_t count)`. Or finally, by a `mmap` on the file, followed by `madvise(void *addr, size_t length, int advice)` with advice of `MADV_WILLNEED`. Unfortunately, none of `posix_fadvise`, `readahead`, and `madvise` are exported by the [POSIX](http://p3rl.org/POSIX) module. So you'll have to find another module (check CPAN) or resort to [Inline](http://p3rl.org/Inline) or XS. Or `open`/`sysread` (less efficient).
- You can combine your videos together. That should completely eliminate transition time.